# Nest.js access process.env at controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, nestjs

How i can access process.env.SOME_FIELD in nest.js ?

**app.module.ts**

```
...
modules: [
...
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            envFilePath: '.env.' + process.env.APP_CODE
        }),
        CatModule
...
]
...
```

**CatController.ts** in CatModule

```
// Below line is not working
console.log(process.env.APP_CODE) // process.env.APP_CODE is undefined

export class CatController {
    constructor() {
        console.log(process.env.APP_CODE) // This is working
    }
}
```

I need access `process.env.APP_CODE` at CatController.ts before class definition, but, that is undefined

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

the envFilePath is set .env file path
so you should define the env variable in the file
and in controller you can get it like this

```
export class CatController {
   constructor(configService: ConfigService) {}
  
   get() {
     return this.configService.get<string>('APP_CODE')
   }

}
```

more detail useage, u can see the [doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)

Comment: but, i cannot access `get()` method before class definition

Comment: @MERN  u should import  ConfigService from @nestjs/config
then you can use configService whit  ```get()```

Comment: @MERN i suggest u read the doc carefully then you can use it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your app.module.ts imports

```
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env.' + process.env.APP_CODE
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `ConfigModule` you're delegating the call to `config` from `dotenv` to the `ConfigService` which is called asynchronously. Because of this, there's no guarantee that `config` will be called by the time you import the `CatsController` and so the `process.env` retrieval will come back with the base object, not with the extra config values coming from the `.env` file. To fix this, you can add

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config()
```

As the **first two** lines of your `main.ts` and it should resolve your issue.